# Need help to implement WebViewAssetLoader

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have converted an existing game written in `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript` into an Android app by wrapping the game in a native Java app using `WebView` ([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dL6B77Q9A4)). The game uses `HTML5 Canvas` for rendering. All files are stored locally.

The game contains several JS files, which is causing CORS / same-origin errors on a physical device, while running without errors on a virtual device. Apparently the solution is to implement `WebViewAssetLoader`.

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/webapps/load-local-content#java) does not provide a lot of context, and for the inexperienced android developer it is unclear how to actually implement this functionality. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste your source code in assets folder and then use this code to load the index.html file in your webview.

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewClientCompat;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebView;
```

and

```
   final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
.addPathHandler(
    "/assets/",
    new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this)
)
.build();
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.w1);

browser.setWebViewClient(
  new WebViewClientCompat() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(
      WebView view,
      WebResourceRequest request
    ) {
      return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // for API < 21
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(
      WebView view,
      String url
    ) {
      return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(url));
    }
  }
);

// WebSettings webViewSettings = browser.getSettings();

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
browser.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/index.html");
```

with browser being the name/id of the webview in your activity xml.

Also remember to build your files with 'assets' as base and put the files into 'main/android_asset' (yes, I know).